# renaming files based on names of other files in R

Tags: r, file-rename

Right now I have two folders, each with the same number .dat files.  In folder 1, I have my original data files and in folder 2 I have files where I have deleted some data from folder 1 files.  I'm trying to see how missing data can change my average, so I am randomly deleting some data then performing the same statistics to see how much it differs from the original data set  So in folder one I have files that have names

kn_2014_01_09_0600.dat
kn_2014_01_09_0700.dat
kn_2014_01_09_0800.dat 
and so on

After I read them in to R and work them in the way I need I write the files to a new folder where they now have the names

1.dat
2.dat
3.dat 
and so on

How can I change the names in my output folder to match the original names?
So my output file 1.dat should be kn_2014_01_09_0600.dat and my 2.dat file should be kn_2014_01_09_0700.dat and so on

right now I have

```
nfiles <- list.files('new file location')
ofiles <- list.files('original file location')
lapply(nfiles,function(i){file.rename(from=i,to=  )})
```

I don't know what to put for the to argument? I thought it might be something like

```
lapply(nfiles,function(i){file.rename(from=i,to=ofiles[i])})
```

or

```
lapply(nfiles,function(i){file.rename(from=i,to=ofiles[1:length(ofiles)})
```

but neither of those worked.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `file.rename(nFiles, oFiles)`, if the order matches? See `?file.rename` - both arguments can be character vectors, they don't need to be vectors of length 1. You may also need to put the path in front of the filename, if I remember it right.

Comment: Wow, I was really making that more difficult than it needed to be.  I really thought i would have to loop over each file with lapply to do this.  Thanks